# MVC3 redirect to a new page after ajax call

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, redirect

In an ASP.NET MVC3 application
I have a base controller where I override some functions.
And I derive all the controllers from it.

In the Base Controller

I am overriding the `OnAuthorization` event handler to check for some stuff and then return true or false. If the result is true I want to redirect to the home page

```
protected override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    if(CheckValues())
    {
        RedirectToHomePage();
    }

}

public ActionResult RedirectToHomePage()
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

The redirection is working for normal action calls.

But when there is an AJAX CALL the Home page is loading inside a DIV of the page and not as a new page.

Is there a way I can force the entire page to reload and redirect to the homepage when there is an AJAX Call?

I tried to use `Redirect("~/")` to redirect to the root URL but same issue. the page is loading inside the DIV and not in the entire page.

Hope I was clear. thanks a lot for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you doing your AJAX call? If you're using jQuery AJAX then you can use the on success to redirect the page.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/test.html',
    success: function() {
      window.location = "/";
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to do this in your AJAX callback method (javascript client-side) not your C# (server-side).

Answer (score 0):

```
var redirectSucURL = '@Url.Action("MethodName","ControllerName")';
```

after success message 
    success: function (result) {

```
if (true) {
    window.location.href = redirectSucURL;
}
```